# Passing array string php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

i read from text file struct like this:
aaa
bbb
ccc
and write in array , now i need to use this name to do a query, select all colounms with this name and the result write in a csv file, file read work fine but query return only 1 rows , return only ccc the last of array .
help me.

this is my code :

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "tirocinioriginale";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);


    if (!$con) {
        die("Connessione fallita: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $myfile = fopen("aziende1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    //echo fread($myfile,filesize("aziende1.txt"));

    $aziende = array();

    while (!feof($myfile)) {
       $aziende[] = fgets($myfile);
    }
    fclose($myfile);


   echo implode(',',$aziende);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM azienda  WHERE nome IN ('".implode("','",$aziende)."')";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $azienderow = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      array_push($azienderow, $row);
    }
      echo "Connessione successo";

   var_dump($azienderow);


    //$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  /*  $fp = fopen('dumpaziende.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($row as $val) {
      fputcsv($fp, explode($val));
    }

fclose($fp);
*/
  //var_dump($aziende);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

if use my code the result was :
file: 
aitech
ItalData

aitech ,ItaldataConnessione successoarray(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["id_azienda"]=> string(3) "244" ["nome"]=> string(8) "ItalData" ["settore"]=> string(17) "Sviluppo software" ["website"]=> string(5) "sadsa" ["email"]=> string(11) "dasdasddsad" ["curriculum_aziendale"]=> string(9) "dasdasdas" ["tematiche"]=> string(7) "fafdaew" ["n_borse"]=> NULL ["data_stipula_convenzione"]=> string(10) "2018-03-14" ["data_fine_convenzione"]=> string(10) "2018-03-20" ["attiva"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipologia_id"]=> string(1) "3" } }

Comment: Have you checked to see what the value is `$query` is?

Comment: Do a `print_r( $result );` to see what you get back from the query.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Show us a what you get from  `print_r( $aziende );`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tirocinio\dump.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tirocinio\dump.php(31): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM a...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tirocinio\dump.php on line 31

Comment: PLEASE! Edit your question to ADD EXTRA INFORMATION

Comment: only the last one element of the array take i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> echo implode(',',$aziende);
> ```

Produces:

```
aitech ,Italdata
//    ^-- see this space? this is probably the problem
```

The query would render like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM azienda  WHERE nome IN ('aitech ','Italdata')";
//     the trailing space will impact matching --------^
```

You may use:

```
implode("','",array_map('trim',$aziende))
```

or `trim()` in your `while` loop to trim before storing the data.

Comment: If this doesn't fix it, please echo `$query` and show your targeted database values, so that we can confirm that your intended match exists as you have described.